# how to read one string per time in java server socket from a php socket client

Tags: java, php, sockets

I am trying to read a string from php client socket in a java server socket. I am writing two strings in php socket client

```
$this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)
socket_connect($this->socket, $this->host, $this->port)
$text = 'SGSA:PRINT:RECIBO';
socket_write($this->socket, $text,  strlen($text));
$text = 'Mensagem para imprimir';
socket_write($this->socket, $text,  strlen($text));
```

However when I read it in java like below

```
Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
String msg;
try {
   msg =  IOUtils.toString( in );
} finally {
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
}
```

It reads two string together at once.

```
run-single:
SGSA:PRINT:RECIBOMensagem para imprimir
```

How can I read one string per time?

Comment: Try writing a newline character to the socket: `$text = "SGSA:PRINT:RECIBO\n";`. Note the use of double quotes.

Comment: @nickb I tried it but doesn't work yet.

Comment: I would investigate your Java methods then - You're grabbing an input stream and it looks like you're converting the whole stream to a string, perhaps find a way to read the contents of that stream line by line?